# expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am learning C++ templates on vs2015 community.Here is my code, I want to define a template class and call the member function in the `main()` function.

```
template <typename T>
class Arithmetic {
    T _a;
    T _b;
    Arithmetic() {};
public
    Arithmetic(T a, T b) :_a(a), _b(b) {};
    T max const() { return _a + _b; };
    T minus const() { return _a - _b; };
};

int main() {
    Arithmetic<int> ar(5,6);
    cout << ar.max() << endl;
}
```

When I build this program, I get error at the last line. It says:

> Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

What should I do?

Comment: are you by any chance including `Windows.h` ?

Answer (score 38):

For anyone else this might also be because of redefinition of a method or property name. i.e a property and method might have the same name

Comment: Or just using `()` after a property name.

Comment: Oh man you probably just saved me an hour of tearing out my hair.

Answer (score 6):

The error indicates trying to call a function max() that is not defined as a function. Change parenthesis after const keyword to after the identifier max:

```
T max const()...
```

to

```
T max() const ...
```

Answer (score 2):

- Add required header inclusion and `using`
- Add `:` after `public`
- Move `const` to proper position

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename T>
class Arithmetic {
    T _a;
    T _b;
    Arithmetic() {};
public:
    Arithmetic(T a, T b) :_a(a), _b(b) {};
    T max() const { return _a + _b; };
    T minus() const { return _a - _b; };
};

int main() {
    Arithmetic<int> ar(5,6);
    cout << ar.max() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be caused if you are sending non-constant values into the max method.

This is the syntax for max:

```
constexpr const T& max (const T& a, const T& b, Compare comp);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not syntax, but definition.